# Get Push id From firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how to get Push id From Firebase for specific value ? here what i done but its not woking for me

```
  final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference();

        myRef.keepSynced(true);



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                myRef.orderByChild("age").equalTo("24").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Log.d("User key", child.getKey());// i spouse this will return me my push id witch is -KUYQqvT3hh91B2AtjTB
                            Log.d("User ref", child.getRef().toString());
                            Log.d("User val", child.getValue().toString());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Here is my firebase console [image: Firebase console]

Comment: why down voute for  me ?

Comment: What is your Log? (from this line - Log.d("User key", child. get Key()))

Comment: it for key i consider  it will Return me  "KUYQqvT3hh91B2AtjTB"

Comment: "how to get Push id From Firebase for specific value" - KUYQqvT3hh91B2AtjTB is your Push id.

Comment: yas but i copy from firebase console manuale

Comment: i want to get push id programmatically

Comment: You can save that push id in an normal String.. 
Or you want to get the push id when you save the user into Firebase?

Comment: this is good idea thanks bro